# Ajax Toolkit ReorderList Two components with the same id 'componentid' can't be added to the applicaiton

Tags: ajax, toolkit, reorderlist

Line 3655
Char  59
Ajax Toolkit ReorderList Two components with the same id 'componentid' can't be added to the applicaiton. When using with a database to update a simple list it works fine until it is being used very fast dragging multiple things reasonably fast. This occurs in IE, Firefox and Chrome. It appears to be something that allows the same id to be created at a guess though it is in the bowls of the Ajax toolkit somewhere. Does anyone have the answer - else I'm off to painstakingly debug the toolkit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up implementing using Jquery plugin. Works much nicer and cleaner than the the MS Ajax toolkit ReorderList. This was not happening on the asp.net at there was no database attached